# Keras - Should I normalize my inputs even if I'm using ImageGenerator?

Tags: keras

I'm working with RGB images and I'm using image generators because (1) they don't fit into memory and (2) I want to apply data augmentation.

I used to normalize my inputs to the range `[0, 1]` before feeding them to a neural network. Now, I see there is a `rescale` parameter in Keras ImageGenerator class. Does it replace the normalization if I say `rescale=1/255.0` ?

Comment: do you accept the answer or would you like more info?

Comment: hey thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rescale`: rescaling factor. Defaults to None. If None or 0, no rescaling is applied, otherwise we multiply the data by the value provided (after applying all other transformations).

Essentially you can just use `ImageDataGenerator()` to augment the dataset and after all steps, the data will be rescaled by the factor you provided.